# Getting access forbidden when calling a SendGrid API

Tags: sendgrid

Trying to invoke https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces (https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/bounces-api/retrieve-all-bounces) and I get a message of "access forbidden".

I am passing in a valid API Key, which is from a free new account.

**API**:
GET
**Headers**:
Authorization Bearer SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept application/json

**Response**:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": null,
            "message": "access forbidden"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the API key have the permission to make requests to that endpoint?

Comment: @philnash I've tested the API Key to Send Emails, it works so this should work?

Comment: Not necessarily, SendGrid API keys can be given very granular permissions. The permission to send emails only allows a key to send emails, and not other things. I would check your API key in the SendGrid dashboard and generate a new one that has all the permissions you need and try again.